# LINQ query take(count) from collection of child elements

Tags: sql, linq, nested

How can I make LINQ query (I am using Entity Framework) that returns top n elements in a child collection?

Here are example classes

```
public class A {
    public int ID 
    public ICollection<B> bData
}

public class B {
    public int ID 
    public string Name
}
```

This is kind of query I was thinking;

```
db.A.Where(a => a.ID == query_id).Include(a => a.bData.Take(count)).ToList();
```

Normally this doesn't work, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Include` method is intended for eager loading the related entity data. It's all or nothing and cannot be used for filtering, sorting, grouping etc.

So what are you asking for can be accomplished with projection (select). It would be simpler if you project to anonymous or custom type (a.k.a. DTO object), because EF does not allow projecting to entity type. But it's still doable by using anonymous type projection in LINQ to Entities query and doing second projection in LINQ to Objects to attach the filtered child collection to its parent entity like this:

```
var result = db.A
    .Where(a => a.ID == query_id)
    .Select(a => new { a, bData = a.bData.Take(count).ToList() })
    .AsEnumerable() // Switch to LINQ to Object context
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.a.bData = x.bData;
        return x.a;
    })
   .ToList();
```

Please note that in order the above to work, `bData` member should not be `virtual` or `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` should be `false` (i.e. lazy loading should be off, otherwise the `bData` collections will be fully reloaded when first accessed).

Comment: Even `.Select(x => x.a)` will do. EF already connected the entities by relationship fixup.

Comment: @GertArnold Ah, forgot about these little tricks :) However I'm getting a bit different result when there are no child records - empty list in the first case and `null` in the second.

Comment: Hmm, never seen that. Don't see it happening here either in a quick test. Don't know what could be going on there.

Comment: @GertArnold May be you are initializing the navigation collection in the constructor / getter?

Comment: Yeah, should be it.